# Block a NSThread in MainThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, concurrency

i've a problem...

I need this:

Create a new thread, and pause it (waiting for a notification from the MainThread ) .
In the MainThread pull a trigger to resume this background thread.

In MainThread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

In background thread:

```
- (void) startTheBackgroundJob {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"+ Thread %@ started and waiting.", self.identifier);
        // Pause Here
        NSLog(@"- Thread %@ unlocked", self.identifier);

        [Scheduler doneTransaction: self];
    }
}
```

MainThread:

```
- (void) unlock {
    // resume a background thread
}
```

I've tried NSLock, NSConditionLock and Semaphore GCD....

Comment: How did you try using locks and semaphores, show that code.

Comment: @Wain https://gist.github.com/iagocc/b2086b0abc329d46abca

Comment: I guess ARC is prematurely releasing the semaphore. Try making the attribute __strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classic scenario when you need to use a *NSCondition* object. The thread needs to wait until some condition is true, so you achieve this by using *lock*, *wait* and *signal*:

```
[sharedCondition lock];
while(!go)
{
    [sharedCondition wait];
}
[sharedCondition unlock];
```

To notify the thread you should signal the condition:

```
[sharedCondition lock];
go= YES;
[sharedCondition signal];
[sharedCondition unlock];
```

Comment: I've tried, not work here: https://gist.github.com/iagocc/b4910a2dba109452d80e
Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and it works: it prints: "+ Thread Transaction 1 started and waiting." and "- Thread Transaction 1 unlocked". SO my guess is that your code doesn't work elsewhere, probably in the class that calls start and unlock. I suggest to put a breakpoint there to see what happens while you call these methods.

Comment: Yep, same for me.  I got the code above to work, though I did remove the while loop and one of the "unlock" calls.  Ramy - is there a particular reason you called [sharedCondition unlock] after the while loop?  https://gist.github.com/meacreatio/5937894

Comment: @javaMe This is just in case that the condition needs to be reused. In the case the OP doesn't reuse it, but it's just for correctness and to show the way of using conditions.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri thank you.
The problem is my app is command line tool, after read your helps I tried create new project, now all looks good.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to put your background thread in a while loop.  Once your main thread reaches the point where you want to allow your background thread to continue, you simply kick your background thread out of the while loop.  For example:

```
...
self.stayInLoop = YES; // BOOL in header - initialized before your thread starts
...

- (void)startTheBackgroundJob {
    while (stayInLoop) {
        // here your background thread stays in this loop (waits) until you 
        // change the flag
    }
    // more background thread code to be executed after breaking out of the loop
}

- (void)unlock {
    self.stayInLoop = NO;
}
```

Comment: At least put a delay / sleep in the loop.

Comment: Because otherwise the background thread will run continuously and take all of the CPU time (at least for 1 processor core).

Comment: For enough, but if you hard code a delay, say for 1 sec, you have the potential of having a 1 sec delay after the main thread breaks the background thread out of the loop which will cause lag in the app.  I can't say how long the dev wants to have this thread spinning but a short wait should be fine.  That being said, a consumer / producer (ie wait / notify all) construct would admittedly be better than my solution for long running delays.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints in to verify your NSLog statements are being hit?